# Unsure about Shirk

Tags: shirk

When I dream, I dream of other people and they are from different religions such as chirstianity, does that mean I commit shirk? Also a few months ago, me and siblings were playing a guessing game where an animation was flipping cards. I didn’t think it was anything or believe it was magical, as my siblings and I just thought it was someone spying on us, so I left the game. The point is I don’t know whether I committed shirk? Also I’ve gotten to the point where I say I’m going to hell, even today when I made mistakes about my ghusl, I thought to myself don’t bother as you’re going to die a sinner. I suffer from waswasa so I don’t know
any more.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum
No doubt that no one is perfect but Allah. There are chances that everyone knowingly or unknowingly commits sins. However, the best approach is that we should be fearful due to our sins but should also be hopeful for the Mercy and Forgiveness of Allah. We will for sure go to hell due to our sins if Allah will do justice. Of course,  Allah is (الحكم) The Judge; The Ultimate Arbiter and (العدل) The Utterly Just. However, He is also (الغفور) The All-Forgiving and (الرحيم) The Merciful. His Mercifulness is much greater than all other names or attributes of Allah. This has been told in many hadiths. This is the only hope every Muslim has that their prayers for forgiveness will be accepted and they will be forgiven for all sins they are really ashamed of and seek mercy for.
My suggestion is that, please think like "I am a sinner, and in the end I have to go to hellfire". Instead, you should think that "I am a sinner but have high hopes going to Jannah due to Mercifulness of Allah (because Allah Himself said)".
Allah does not like if someone does not thinks that He is indeed Merciful. One Hadith said (Sahih Bukahari: [7405](https://sunnah.com/urn/69580))

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah says: '**I am just as My slave thinks I am, (i.e., I am able to do for him what he thinks I can do for him)** and I am with him if He remembers Me. If he remembers Me in himself, I too, remember him in Myself; and if he remembers Me in a group of people, I remember him in a group that is better than they; and if he comes one span nearer to Me, I go one cubit nearer to him; and if he comes one cubit nearer to Me, I go a distance of two outstretched arms nearer to him; and if he comes to Me walking, I go to him running.' "

Allah knows better. May Allah accept what I stated correctly. May Alalh forgive me if I have stated something incorrectly unknowingly or knowingly.

Answer (score 0):

Waswas are indeed a great problem which may bit by bit, lead to the ruin of your life. What erases these doubts? **Knowledge**

Essentially, if you have done something out of forgetfulness, which may be a mockery of religion and otherwise disbelief. You are not held accountable for that and ignore all doubts.
And whatever sort of dream you have doesnt change the fact that you are muslim.

And Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

Assalam o Allaikum.

Let me just be short and get straight to your question that "*....whether I committed shirk?..*".

I don't know whether this is Haram or not. But, I surely do know that this can not be considered as ‘Shirk’. Because shirk is the act that means to worship someone else other than ‘Allah’ or to include any other being in worship along with ‘Allah’, which apparently you are not doing.